# iOS app rejected due to copyright issues

Tags: ios

an app I have been working on got rejected by Apple,
here is the message I got from Apple when it got rejected:

From Apple
    22.2 - Apps that contain false, fraudulent or misleading representations or use names or icons similar to other Apps will be rejected

22.2 Details 
Your app or its metadata contains misleading content.

Specifically, the app screenshots and splash screen are from a well known TV show belonging to Keshet without the rights to use it.

We’ve attached screenshot for your reference.

Next Steps

Please remove or revise any misleading content in your app and its metadata.

Since your iTunes Connect Application State is Rejected, a new binary will be required. Make the desired metadata changes when you upload the new binary.

NOTE: Please be sure to make any metadata changes to all App Localizations by selecting each specific localization and making appropriate changes.*

some background,
I did develop this app for Keshet with permission, but I did not include any kind of permission from Keshet when submitting.
Yes, my bad, I just didn't know it was required.

Anyway, my question is,
would replying to Apple through the resolution center and including a document from Keshet's legel dept. be enough to resolve this issue?
or do I need to go through the whole process again, submitting a new binary etc.?
or perhaps something else?

Also, does this kind of rejection means that every other aspect of the game I submitted is okay?
because they only reacted to the rights to use Keshet's properties.

Comment: Yes. You should follow the instruction from the resolution center and resubmit the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow the instructions Apple gave you. (For example: "Since your iTunes Connect Application State is Rejected, a new binary will be required.")

Apple never promises that every other aspect is ok. Ever. Even the fact that you're updating an existing product doesn't promise that there won't be rejection due to things that were tacitly approved in previous versions. The only approval that really matters is when you see your app on the app store, and even then they sometimes retroactively reject apps that are already there. There are no guarantees in life.

StackOverflow isn't going to be able to give you any better information or advice than Apple will. If you have questions about their current process (which changes from time to time anyway), you need to speak with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [App Store Review Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#legal-requirements) before you submit your App to App Store. In your case of Copyright issue follow section number 22 - Legal Requirements.

If you have copyrights to use particular Image , Logo or content then send that reference while submission to App Store.

After removal of objectionable content from project create new build and upload it again to App Store submission process.